# Help to get variable in a pseudo random lottery contract

Tags: random

Hi everyone at the other side!

I'm doing a pseudo random lottery contract on solidity. It's working 100% good. The logic of the contract is that a player pays for getting a number in order to match with the number that owner put when did deploy. If it's match the jackpot is splitted in both. But, I cannot get the way to show the user the number that he/she got. I want to do that in order to then develop a DApp and show transparency to user. The variable call "numero" is what I want to do a getter, but it doesn't work.

Please, your help will be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Loteriados{
    

    address internal owner;         //creador del contrato
    uint256 internal num;           //contador numero de intentos
    uint256 public precio;          //precio para participar
    uint256 public numeroGanador;   //numero ganador definido por el creador del contrato
    bool public juego;              //indicador si o no esta habilitado el juego para jugar
    address public ganador;         //direccion wallet del ganador de la Loteria
    uint256 public fondoInicial;    //pozo inicial aportado por el creador del contrato
//    uint256 public numero;          //numero obtenido al participar 



//seteo de las variables iniciales e instrucciones que ocurren por unica vez en el deploy
    constructor(uint256 _numeroGanador, uint256 _precio) public payable{
        owner = msg.sender;
        num = 0;
        numeroGanador = _numeroGanador;
        precio = _precio;
        juego = true;
        fondoInicial = msg.value;
    }

//modificador que obliga a que el valor pagado por participante sea igual al precio por particiar
    modifier filtroPrecio(){
        require(precio == msg.value);
        _;
    }

//modificador que define que olo el creador pueda ejecutar partes del contrato
    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

//funcion que define la pseudo aleatoriedad, para el resultado del participante    
    function numeroRandom() private view returns(uint256){
        return uint256( keccak256( abi.encode(block.timestamp, msg.sender, num) ) ) % 10;
    }

//funcion que comprueba si el participante ha acertado 
    function comprobarAciertos(uint256 _numUsuario) private view returns(bool){
        if(_numUsuario == numeroGanador)
                {return true;}
        else    {return false;}    
        }
    
//funcion core del juego de loteria, pide que lo pagado sea igual al precio
    function participar() external payable filtroPrecio returns(bool resultado, uint256 numero){
        require(juego == true);                                 //el juego tiene que estar habilidado para jugar
        uint256 numUsuario = numeroRandom();                    //define que numUsuario es el dado por la funcion psudo aleatoria
        bool acierto = comprobarAciertos(numUsuario);           //usando la funcion comprobarAciertos define si o no el usuario ha acertado
        if(acierto == true)                                     //Si se ha acertado
            {juego = false;                                         //se para eljuego
            msg.sender.transfer((address(this).balance)/2);         //se transfiere la mitad del balance al participante
            ganador = msg.sender;                                   //se obtiene el adress wallet del participante
            resultado = true;                                       //se dice que el acierto es verdadero
            numero = numUsuario;                                   //se escribe el numero del usuario en variable numero
            }
            
        else(acierto == false);                                 //si el participante no ha acertado
            {num = num + 1;                                         //se suma 1 al contador para registrar un nuevo intento
            resultado = false;                                      //se dice que el resultado es falso
            numero = numUsuario;                                    //se escribe el numero del usuario en variable numero
            }                                   
    }


//funcion getter para ver el pozo del premio mientras se encuentre activo el juego    
    function verPremio() public view returns(uint256) {
        if(juego == true)
            {return address(this).balance/2;}
        else
            {return 0;}
    }    
    

//funcion que permite al creador del contrato retirar 50% del monto siepre y cuando un participante haya ganado antes
 function retirarFondosContrato() onlyOwner external returns(uint256) {
        require(juego == false);                                        //ni siquiera el creador puede sacar monto, esto es transparencia!!
        uint256 pagoCreador = address(this).balance;
        msg.sender.transfer(pagoCreador);
        return pagoCreador;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a public variable you don't need a getter. The compiler already creates one with the variable name.

```
uint256 public numero;
```

From js it can be called like this `const num = await myContract.methods.numero()`.

It should be easy to write a getter in any case

```
function getNumero() public view returns (uint256) {
    return numero;
}
```

---

###### Old answer

There's a bug in `participar` function. The else clause is followed by a comparison `(acierto == false)` that does nothing.

Probably you wanted to surround the whole block with `{}`

```
    else { // (acierto == false);                                 //si el participante no ha acertado
        num = num + 1;                                         //se suma 1 al contador para registrar un nuevo intento
        resultado = false;                                      //se dice que el resultado es falso
        numero = numUsuario;                                    //se escribe el numero del usuario en variable numero
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ismael, thanks for replying back. But my problem is really how to do a getter function for variable called "numero". I wanna show it to the user in every try that he/she does. Can you help me on that?

Comment: @MarioSaavedraVergara It should be easy to write a getter, see the updated answer, but perhaps it is not needed.